# Bind hardware to specific /dev/input/event*

Tags: udev

I have 2 gamepads and a game that always takes the first gamepad from all /dev/input/event* entrys (Bastion).

Because this is kinda random i want to bind one game controller to always get /dev/input/event100 and the other one to always get /dev/input/event101.

Is there a clean way to do it and how?

Comment: Can you post output of `ls -l /dev/input/by-id /dev/input/by-path` ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QgBR9VG8

The second controller is not listed, don't know why, maybe because i use xboxdrv.service, but evtest recognizes it: http://pastebin.com/t5SCAqCP

Comment: In given output, I guess one game controller has occupied `event` and other one had occupied `event16`. If this is so, then you can easily `/dev/input/by-id/usb-Bison_BisonCam__NB_Pro-event-if00` and other link in Xorg to bind it permanently

Comment: problem is i can*t specify what path is used, the game i want to play just checks /dev/input/event* which can be random and not be ordered by the user.
My current workaround is to manually "$ mv /dev/input/event16 /dev/input/event101" but i'm not sure if it breaks something and i'm also looking for a more permanent solution.
My only idea is to write a startup script that uses /dev/input/by-id/ to automate that process but that's not a clean way.